# openssl_pkey_get_private return null PHP Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework2, openssl, rsa, digital-signature

I have private key here:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
...<< private_key_bits' => 2048 >>...
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

i want to encrypt string, this is my code:

```
$rsa = Rsa::factory(array(
            'public_key'    => 'public_key_'.$username.'.pub',
            'private_key'   => 'private_key_'.$username.'.pem',
            'pass_phrase'   => $username.' '.date("Y/m/d h:i:s").'',
            'binary_output' => false
        ));
        $encrypt = $rsa->encrypt($content);
```

it return an error:
`Unable to load private key; openssl error:0906D06C`
I saw in zend/crypt then try to print_r parameters, it right. name of key private, pass phrase.. was true, then i print_r `openssl_pkey_get_private` result:

```
 public function __construct($pemString, $passPhrase = null)
    {
    $result = openssl_pkey_get_private($pemString, $passPhrase);
    print_r($result);
    die();
    if (false === $result) {
        throw new Exception\RuntimeException(
            'Unable to load private key; openssl ' . openssl_error_string()
        );
    }
```

but `openssl_pkey_get_private` return null. i don't know whats wrong with my private key.

Comment: Are you using linux? can you check the apache error log for more info?

Comment: @joao i use windows.. yes i checked but no record about zend. finally i use zend server. and all works normally